# parenthesis and relative clause

Tags: parentheses

I have a question about why a parenthesis is necessary in a sentence instead of a relative clause:
Why it should be:

> Such an impact, many scientists believe, would have blocked the planet with debris.

Instead of:

> Such an impact many scientists believe would have blocked the planet with debris.

I think I can understand the second one as "Many scientists believe such an impact would have blocked the planet with debris.

byw, it is a question from ACT English.

Comment: Look up "parenthetical phrase".

Comment: There's no relative clause in your second example. What makes you think there is?

Comment: @BillJ, I think it could be viewed as " such an impact (that) many  scientists believe would have blocked the planet with debris," within which the antecedent is "an impact."

Comment: "(That) many scientists believe would have blocked the planet with debris," is not a relative clause, but a declarative content clause functioning as a complement in the noun phrase "such an impact". In any case, it's the sentence as it's written that should be parsed.

Comment: It's parenthetical because it can be taken out of the sentence and still leave the meaningful sentence. "Such an impact would have blocked the planet with debris". The parenthetical phrase "many scientists believe" softens the sentence and makes the statement less didactic but it does not, fundamentally, change the meaning. As it is parenthetical it is marked by commas.